# (PHP) Error al cargar imagen con fopen() a traves de $_FILES

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo dificultades al subir una imagen con la herramienta fopen().

El codigo html es el siguiente:

```
    <form method="POST" action="images.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="estilo" placeholder="Estilo">
        <input type="text" name="ingredientes" placeholder="Ingredientes" maxlength="100">
        <input type="number" name="precio" placeholder="Precio">
        <label>Cargar Imagen</label>
        <input type="file" name="img" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Cargar">
    </form>
    
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
        echo "<h1>El tamaño de la imagen no debe superar los 50kb";
    }
    if(isset($_GET['ok'])) {
        echo "<h1>Derecho a la base de datos :)</h1>";
    }
    ?>
```

Y el codigo PHP es:

```
<?php
$estilo=$_POST['estilo'];
$ingredientes=$_POST['ingredientes'];
$precio=$_POST['precio'];

$img_name=$_FILES['img']['name'] ?? null;
$img_size=$_FILES['img']['size'] ?? null;
$img_type=$_FILES['img']['type'] ?? null;
$img_temp=$_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] ?? null;

$top_size = 200000;

//............................................

if($img_size>$top_size) {
    header("Location: unidad4.php?error");

} else {
    $archivo = fopen($img_temp, "a+");
    $img_db = fread($archivo, $img_size);

    $img_db = addslashes($img_db);
    include("conect.php");
    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO productos VALUES (DEFAULT, '$estilo', '$ingredientes',  
$precio, '$img_db', '$img_type')");
    header("Location unidad4.php?ok");  
}
?>
```

De los cuales obtengo el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_AVANZADO\base_evaluaciones\images.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_AVANZADO\base_evaluaciones\images.php(19): fopen('', 'a+') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_AVANZADO\base_evaluaciones\images.php on line 19

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que hace ese "a+" dentro del fopen()?

Comment: abre el archivo en modo lectura y escritura. Lo que intento hacer, ademas de cargar datos alfanumericos en la base de datos, es cargar tambien informacion de tipo archivo, en este caso una imagen, que luego quiero traer de la base de datos para modificarla y presentarla a conveniencia.

Answer (score 0):

si quieres guardar la imagen en un archivo txt usa fopen, pero la imagen la debes pasar a una cadena de texto, lo mas comun es usar base 64, pero el archivo seria muy grande.
Lo mejor es mover la imagen al servidor y en la db guardar el path de esta imagen o en el txt si sigues con fopen.
para pasar la imagen a base64 te dejo esta guia

```
$path = 'image.png'; 
// Extensión de la imagen
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
// Cargando la imagen
$data = file_get_contents($path); 
// Decodificando la imagen en base64
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data); 
// Mostrando la imagen
echo '<img src="'.$base64.'"/>'; 
// Mostrando el código base64
echo $base64;
```

Me cuentas si te sirve esta opcion, hay convertidores online para que hagas la prueba directa, luego pongas el codigo

Comment: Muchas gracias daniel, voy a chekear y vuelvo al rato. GRACIAS!